# How to generate an Office Add-in SSO token from within a dialog window

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

I'm building an Office 365 Add-in for MS Word. It needs to generate a SSO token which is used to invoke an API.

I'm able generate an SSO token when running a Taskpane window itself. However, the same code fails with the below error when being invoked from a dialog window.

I've got a button in the Taskpane which opens a dialog window like this:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://myAddinDomain/myDialog.html');
```

The dialog window then tries to get an SSO token like this:

```
await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({ allowSignInPrompt: true });
```

However the following error is thrown by the above function:

```
{
    name: 'Permission Denied',
    message: "You don't have sufficient permissions for this action.",
    code: 7000
}
```

My assumption at this stage is that it's due to the [limitation outlined here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#open-a-dialog-box-from-a-host-page) that you cannot open a dialog from within a dialog and perhaps that's what the `getAccessToken` function is trying to do. That would explain why I'm able to get the token within the taskpane but not the dialog.

If that's the case how do I generate an SSO token from the dialog window?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken` method from any event handler in the add-in which triggers your dialog to be displayed and then pass a token as a parameter to the dialog window.

That is not really a good idea to display a dialog and then try to call SSO which could also display dialog windows.

Comment: That's the approach we've gone for as a work around but it doesn't feel like a great solution. The length of the token is unknown and there's a reasonable possibility it exceeds the maximum length allowed in a URL so passing it as a URL param to the dialog may not be ideal. Is there another way of passing parameters to the dialog? We've also explored local storage bit again this isn't an option as the taskpane and dialog window don't share storage contexts.

Comment: You can use other possible ways for storing the token like user/custom properties or local storage. I agree - that is not the best way for keeping such secrets. So, I may recommend posting a feature request for that. Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Answer (score 0):

Eugene is correct. Also, note this from the article that you linked to:

- The messageParent function is one of only two Office JS APIs that can be called in the dialog box.
- The other JS API that can be called in the dialog box is Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported.

So, you can't call getAccessToken from inside a dialog.